# GWT Tutorial stockwatcher.nocache.js filename

Tags: gwt

Where is the name of the javascript "stockwatcher.nocache.js" file name defined?
For example, how could I change this to "stockwatcher1.nocache.js"?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not be changing it. What is your final intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the compiled folder (`stockwatcher/`) and the compiled js file (`stockwatcher.nocache.js`) is based on either the package and name of the module file (so `com/acme/project/Project.gwt.xml` would create `com.acme.project.Project.cache.js` inside a `com.acme.project.Project/` directory), or based on the `rename-to` attribute of the `<module>` tag in that module file. For example, if this is your module file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='stockwatcher'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
...
```

Then the output files will be in the `stockwatcher/` directory, and the main script will be `stockwatcher.nocache.js`. If you change this to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='stockwatcher1'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
...
```

and either recompile or start dev mode, you'll now have a `stockwatcher1/` directory, and a `stockwatcher1.nocache.js` file in it.

Comment: Any way to have the directory name and the filename prefix be different?